# How to read systemd journal file on system that has no systemd?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to troubleshoot a system (Arch Linux) that had systemd installed.

The volume has been mounted on an Ubuntu system (14.04) that has no systemd installed.

How can I troubleshoot said systemd journal without switching the host box to systemd?

`apt-get install journalctl` does not work.

Comment: Use a version of Linux that runs systemd such as Arch, Fedora, or Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: You don't need to switch to systemd, just the journalctl binary is needed ... which unfortunately is not available for 14.04 (all PPAs for it seem to be defunct). Even 14.10 would do.

Comment: @bodhi.zaen This would be the obvious solution but not it is currently not possible.

Comment: @muru so I gues it would be best to upgrade the host to a more recent ubuntu version.

Comment: A VM, or a LXC container might be simpler and safer.

Comment: No. upgrading to 15.04 will not help: **ubuntu's journalctl** is not *compatible* with archlinux'journal file. Archlinux use **lz4** compression while ubuntu use **xz** compression. So one can not read journal file from a system with journalctl from the other system.  a simple chroot should be enough, no ?

Comment: try using an archlinux live disk

Comment: Since the `systemd` package is stored in git, you could `git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-systemd/systemd.git` and read the source, steal from it, or enter the adventure of trying to build systemd on 14.04

Comment: I'm just wondering, won't a chroot help with this?

Answer (score 6):

`chroot` into the Arch Linux system:

```
cd /location/of/arch/root
chroot /location/of/arch/root /bin/bash
```

journalctl looks for the journal files in `/var/log/journal/machine-id/`. If you boot up with a rescue OS that has a different machine ID or a different root it hence won't find any data there.

Hence,

a) use `journalctl --directory=/var/log/journal/<machine-id>`

b) or `journalctl -m`

The "-m" swicth merges the journals of all directories in `/var/log/journal/*`, hence makes it unnecessary to figure out the machine id of the host.

[Source](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86034)

Comment: I've tested this with Ubuntu 16.04/Arch Linux, but could not get my hands on a 14.04.

Answer (score -2):

the command line partition recovery program called [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) should allow some manipulation to the systemd (Arch Linux) volume

---

this not not a full or "good" solution. but TestDisk can

1. Rebuild a partition table, recover deleted partition
2. Locate the ext2/ext3/ext4 Backup SuperBlock
3. Copy files from deleted a ext2/ext3/ext4 partition.
4. handle a non-partitioned volume
5. Rewrite the Master boot record (MBR)

give it a try.

> **$** sudo apt-get install testdisk

start it

> **$** sudo testdisk

press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to create a new log & select the disk with the volume you want to manipulation

select the partition table type.  
yours is Intel

from here you can

- view  files
- Copy files

hope it helps

Comment: More information on how to use __TestDisk__ would be helpful in case the link _breaks_ in the future.

Comment: @George  is this what you wanted?

Comment: That's a good start but look at the bottom of the link you would __see a section__ called __documentation__ there you find __a step by step__ link try that, but note that a down vote has been done on your answer so consider the question again before updating your post.